# Objective C Regular Expression removing everything except numbers

Tags: objective-c, nsregularexpression

I want to remove all character, the things that I need is number from 0 - 9

Could you please show me some example to solve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could make your own NSCharacterSet and then trim out every character not contained within it by using its invertedSet. Here's an example:

```
NSString *stringWithLettersAndNumbers = @"345345345fff";

NSCharacterSet *myCharset = [NSCharacterSet characterSetWithCharactersInString:@"0123456789"];
NSString *newString = [stringWithLettersAndNumbers stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[myCharset invertedSet]];

NSLog(@"%@",newString);
```

Answer (score 2):

Regular expressions are great for this sort of stuff:

```
NSString *orgStr = @"letters34243more32132letters";

NSString *result = [orgStr stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString: @"\\D"
                                                     withString: @""
                                                        options: NSRegularExpressionSearch
                                                          range: NSMakeRange(0, orgStr.length)];
```

What it does is find any non-digit character (defined as `\D`) and replace it with an empty string, i.e., remove it.

It does it for any such character, irrespectively of its position in the string. In my reading of the question, this is what you need.

The double backslash ("\") in the pattern string is necessary because NSString literals need an extra backslash to escape the "real" one.

Answer (score 0):

Loop through the string and pickup all digits.

```
NSMutableString *strResult = [NSMutableString string];
for (int position=0; position<text.length; position++) {
  unichar c = [text characterAtIndex:position];
  NSCharacterSet *numericSet = [NSCharacterSet decimalDigitCharacterSet];
  if ([numericSet characterIsMember:c]) {
    [strResult appendFormat:@"%C", c]; 
  }
}
```

Comment: No worries. Please notice unichar is deferent from char.

Comment: isn't this answer waaay more expensive than doing a regex like what the OP originally asked for?

Comment: @abbood good point. I didn't compare the ASM code. But I think regex also can't avoid looping in low level. Please correct me if I am wrong.